# Reference for phase diagrams of elements

Tags: elements, phase-diagram

I am trying to answer this question:

**What is the pressure inside a sealed container with liquid nitrogen at room temperature?**

Can you help me find a good online reference for phase diagrams. I am especially interested in pure elements, and diatomic gasses.

Comment: First thing I do is type *"phase diagram of <stuff>"* into google.

Comment: @dmckee: Off cause that was the very first thing I tried - no luck.

Comment: When I did I found [a Wolfram alpha result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=nitrogen+phase+diagram) which shows that $\mathrm{N}_2$ is above it's critical point at room temperature, so there isn't really an answer (there is no "liquid" as such, just dense fluid at whatever pressure you can maintain).

Comment: @dmckee: Can you answer what the pressure inside a container, filled with liquid nitrogen, sealed, and then heated to room temperature will be? Maybe I should post it as separate question!?

Comment: 1L liquid : 694L gas, the pressure depends on the container, most likely it will burst before such a high pressure is reached.

Comment: The liquid density is about 0.8 g/cm^3. The STP gas density is 1.26 g/l (i.e. about 0.00126 g/cm^3). Both of these figures are easy to find with a web search. From these you can get Alexander's estimate under the assumption of a ideal gas, though that assumption probably dosen't hold.

Comment: @dmckee You should post your comment as an answer, so Hans-Peter could accept it.  I'm sorry, I've answered only because I've overlooked your comment thread...

Comment: @Alexander: One thing that the phase diagram shows is that the ideal gas law can not be used to make the estimate. The answer is **not 694 atm**. http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29523/pressure-of-sealed-in-liquid-nitrogen

Comment: @dmckee: See my comment to Alexander. I will accept your Wolfram link as answer to this question. - have posted a new one: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29523/pressure-of-sealed-in-liquid-nitrogen

Comment: Hi @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen. It seems your new question more or less supersede this question, so I'm closing this as duplicate, even if it is not strictly true.

Comment: @Qmechanic: You are correct - please close it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question only makes sense if you ask

**At which pressure are liquid and gaseous phase of nitrogen at equilibrium at room temperature?**

The answer is none, as critical temperature of [nitrogen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen) is far below room temperature, at about 126 K.

Comment: I am sorry, I've only seen dmckee's comment now.  Maybe dmckee should post his answer too so you could accept it.